# Stopping execution of program after a certain time

Tags: c, timer

I'm not sure what is the best way to implement a function such that the program will terminate itself after a particular amount of time. I thought about using a while loop with a condition that the difference between the start time and end time does not exceed the time limit. However, my program will be doing various activities such as creating new threads and such that a while loop may be intrusive.

Perhaps a better way would be to create a function such as `start_sim_timer(double sim_time)` and make that loop itself in another thread?

Any suggestions on the best way to make a program terminate after a certain period?

Comment: On which operating system? If on Linux, read [time(7)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/time.7.html). Please edit your question to improve it (at least, add the tags relevant to your OS)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the alarm function. It will trigger the time count then it start the execution of 
our code. When the given time is came it will come out from the execution.

```
unsigned int alarm(unsigned int seconds);
```